# Error al intentar usar AbstractController de Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar Symfony y al intentar usar AbstractController me salta el siguiente error

"Attempted to call an undefined method named "getName" of class "App\Controller\TestController".
"

Adjunto imagen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlYps.jpg

Si no uso el "extends AbstractController" y uso por ejemplo extends Bundle y cambio el return por el que esta comentado funciona el codigo. Me lo genera al error cuando cambio de extends.

Me guío de la [documentación de symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-base-controller-classes-services)

Les dejo el código:
src/Controller/TestController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

#use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TestController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
    */
    public function index() {
        //return new Response('test');
        return $this->render('test.html.twig', [
            'test' => '1234',
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

routes.yaml

```
TestController:
    path: /test
    controller: App\Controller\TestController::index
```

y esta agregado en bundles.php

```
App\Controller\TestController::class => ['all' => true],
```

Comment: Creo que no tienes que añadir la clase TestController al archivo 'bundles.php', ya que no se trata de un bundle. Si quieres que sea un bundle debe extender de la clase Bundel. Échale un ojo a la documentación: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

Comment: Era eso. Muchas Gracias por la información!